# CA1062 not evaluating on .Net Standard 2.0 class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, ca1062

I'm unable to get CA1062 (validate arguments of public methods) to evaluate.

I've created a .Net Standard 2.0 C# class library and installed `Microsoft.CodeQuality.Analyzers` and several others nuget packages as per this screenshot:
[image: Analyzers for the project]

I've also enabled CA1062 in the ruleset for the project, as per the image:

[image: CA1062 is enabled in the ruleset]

I've created this class to test if CA1062 (validate arguments of public methods) does evaluate:

```
public class Person
{
    public String Name { get; }
    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public void DeclareWarOn(Person enemy)
    {
        String enemyName = enemy.Name;
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.Name} declared war on {enemyName}");
    }
}
```

In the `DeclareWarOn` method the parameter `enemy` is never checked for a `null` value but is used in the line `String enemyName = enemy.Name;`

This is suppose to trigger CA1062, but it is not triggered.

Other rules do evaluate. As example, I have created an `internal` Exception class as such:

```
internal class MyException : Exception 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

And this did indeed trigger the relevant code analysis warning for it (CA1064).
However I can't get CA1062 to evaluate.

Comment: at first I though along the line of "could it be smart enough to detect that there is no default constructor, and no instance of `Person` could ever be constructed without a name", but you can still call `DeclareWarOn(null);` so that would be a bug of the analyzer.

Comment: Found any solution yet ? got the same problem here. The same goes for CA1031 and CA1047. But others like CA1063, CA1716, CA1816 are detected correctly. I don't understand why some rules work and others don't.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I also have a lot of other CA rules not evaluating correctly, even despite setting each rule to evaluate as an error.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing for CA1063 with .NET Core 2.0, though bizarrely it's inconsistent. `foreach (var e in listParam)` evaluates but not `foreach (var e in listParam.Select(x => x)`

Comment: @Jonathan see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently removed all Analyzers and installed a higher version of the FxCop package on this project, and it solved the issue.

(I've added this in case any developer discovers this post and is still searching for a solution)